# Merge/Join 2 jQuery sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, union

Look at this code for example...

```
var $div = $('#my div'),

    $ul = $('#somewhere ul');
```

How can I perform a jQuery method on both of them? For example, would this work? What is best practice here?

```
$($div, $ul).addClass('my-new-class');
```

Wouldn't that search `$div` under a context of `$ul` ?

Comment: yes it would, i also thought the other day same thing now i see that i'm not alone:)

Comment: `$('#my div, #somewhere ul').addClass('my-new-class');` is actually fine, as is `$div.add($ul).addClass('my-new-class');`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jQuery provides the [`add`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add) method for this. The most common case is to add more elements to the jQuery set that match a given selector (passed to `add`), but you can use it to perform a [standard union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of two sets too:

```
$c = $a.add($b).addClass('foo')
```

`add` returns a new wrapped set, containing the merged and unique combination of `this` and the given set. Note that `$b` remains unchanged.

Comment: does `$a` remains unchanged too?

Comment: `$a` remains unchanged. (This is an old thread -- currently using jQuery 3.2.1.)

Comment: Ya someone else added "$b remains unchanged" but didn't specify anything about $a haha. I personally don't recall, thank you @NicholasCloud. Maybe you can edit the answer so this is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very very late, but you can also do the following:

```
$().add($div).add($ul).addClass('my-new-class');
```

Comment: `$div.add($ul)...` makes more sense... I don't see how this adds any value to the already existing answers.

Comment: @FelixKling In one line, not much.  But I'm using the concept behind it:  `var initted = $();` ...later, under one condition, `initted.add($foo)` ...later, under another (not mutually exclusive) condition, `initted.add($foo)` ...and so on.  Being able to start with an [empty set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) is _extremely_ valuable.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$('#my div, #somewhere ul').addClass('my-new-class');
```

look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple)

Comment: I know that will work, but sometimes I set up the 2 caches at the beginning of the script, and I would like to avoid redefining them later within methods etc.